# How can I make a condition to check an appointment if it is available or not in php?

Tags: php

I want to make a condition that determines whether the appointment is available with a particular doctor or not. If it is not available, the condition will execute (return true);
 this is My code I tried to make a condition but it didn't work.

```
     if($_POST){  
   $patient_obj->docId =$_POST['selectDr'];
   $patient_obj->appStart =$_POST['appStart'];
   $patient_obj->appEnd =$_POST['appEnd'];
   $patient_obj->patientId =$_POST['patientId'];

   $startDateInput= $patient_obj->appStart;
   $startDateInput=strtotime($startDateInput);
   $startDateInput= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $startDateInput);

   $endDateInput= $patient_obj->appEnd;
   $endDateInput=strtotime($endDateInput);
   $endDateInput= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $endDateInput);
   

   $sql = "SELECT AppStart,AppEnd,docID FROM appointments WHERE docID=?";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindParam(1,$patient_obj->docid);
   $stmt->execute();
   $data=$stmt->fetch();
    extract($data);
    $startDateInDb=$AppStart;
    $startDateInDb=strtotime($startDateInDb);
    $startDateInDb= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $startDateInDb);
    $endDateInDb=$AppEnd;
    $endDateInDb=strtotime($endDateInDb);
    $endDateInDb= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $endDateInDb);
  if(($startDateInput>=$startDateInDb && $startDateInput <=$endDateInDb) || ($endDateInput >=$startDateInDb && $endDateInput <= $endDateInDb) || ($startDateInput <= $startDateInDb && $endDateInput >=$endDateInDb)) {
       echo'
       <script>
       alert("change the appointment")
       </script>';
  } 
  else{
   $patient_obj->addAppointment();
}
```

Comment: @kenLee how can I change it so it will return all the data, I tried to change it to fechAll() but still not working do you have any advice?

Comment: On the other hand, I am doubtful whether this condition will be sufficient: `(($startDateInput>=$dateStart && $startDateInput<=$dateEnd) && ($endtDateInput>=$dateEnd && $endtDateInput>=$dateStart))`. Normal way to check is ( startdateinput >=startdateindb && startdateinput <=enddateindb) || (enddateinput >=stardateindb && endateinput <= enddateindb) || (startdateinput <= statdateindb && endateinput >=enddateindb) . If this condition is true, then the appointment overlaps with existing appointment(s)

Comment: @kenLee I just change the condition you suggested  and when I try to add a new appointment the appointment does not go to the database whether it's a valid appointment or no

Comment: @kenLee yes I am

Comment: @kenlee actually the condition is not working the appointment still can be chosen more than once

Comment: @kenLee yes I noticed that and I change it but still the same

Comment: @kenLee did it work with you?

Comment: @kenLee yes, I saw these typos but the condition still not working with me.

Comment: I will give you a demo link to see the result soon.

Comment: Please check this link (I have added the details in my revised answer)  : http://www.createchhk.com/SO/testSO28Nov2021a.php (1) Enter the start date and end date which overlaps with existing record and click submit, you will see "Already taken", otherwise you will see "Allow insertion". Please view carefully and then amend the code to suit your needs. Thanks

Comment: @kenLee it's working with me now I had a typo in $docid. thank you so much Mr ken I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: fetch() only returns the 1st record of your query (WHERE docID=?).Hence please add conditions to your query to determine whether there exists any records in the database which overlaps with the newly submitted appointment data.

Hence, Please change the block:

```
$sql = "SELECT AppStart,AppEnd,docID FROM appointments WHERE docID=?";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindParam(1,$patient_obj->docid);
   $stmt->execute();
   $data=$stmt->fetch();
    extract($data);
    $dateStart=$AppStart;
    $dateStart=strtotime($dateStart);
    $dateStart= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateStart);
    $dateEnd=$AppEnd;
    $dateEnd=strtotime($dateEnd);
    $dateEnd= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateEnd);
   
   if (($startDateInput>=$dateStart && $startDateInput<=$dateEnd) && ($endtDateInput>=$dateEnd && $endtDateInput>=$dateStart)) {
      echo'<script> alert("the appointment is already taken");</script>';
    exit();
   }
   else{
     $patient_obj->addAppointment();
  }
```

to

```
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_rows FROM appointments WHERE docID=? and ((AppStart >= ? && AppStart <=?) || (AppEnd >= ? && AppEnd <=?) || (AppStart <= ? && AppEnd >=?))";

   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindParam(1,$patient_obj->docid);
   $stmt->bindParam(2,$startDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(3,$endDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(4,$startDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(5,$endDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(6,$startDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(7,$endDateInput);

   $stmt->execute();

   $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $total_rows = $row['total_rows'];

   if ($total_rows!=0) {
      echo'<script> alert("the appointment is already taken");</script>';
      exit();
   }
   else{
      $patient_obj->addAppointment();
  }
```

To further demonstrate, I have made a testing link , with code as follows:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($_POST) {
$servername="localhost";
$db="xxxxxx";
$username="xxxxxx";
$password="xxxxx";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$docid=$_POST["docid"];
$startDateInput=$_POST["startDateInput"];
$endDateInput=$_POST["endDateInput"];



$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_rows FROM appointments WHERE docID=? and ((AppStart >= ? && AppStart <=?) || (AppEnd >= ? && AppEnd <=?) || (AppStart <= ? && AppEnd >=?))";

   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
/*
   $stmt->bindParam(1,$patient_obj->docid);
   $stmt->bindParam(2,$startDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(3,$endtDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(4,$startDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(5,$endtDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(6,$startDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(7,$endtDateInput);
*/


   $stmt->bindParam(1,$docid);
   $stmt->bindParam(2,$startDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(3,$endDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(4,$startDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(5,$endDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(6,$startDateInput);
   $stmt->bindParam(7,$endtDateInput);



   $stmt->execute();

   $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $total_rows = $row['total_rows'];

   if ($total_rows!=0) {
//      echo'<script> alert("the appointment is already taken");</script>';
//      exit();
 echo "<font color=red>Already taken</font>";
   }
   else{
    //  $patient_obj->addAppointment();
echo "<font color=blue>Allow insertion</font>";
  }
}

  ?>

Current Data in db: <br>
Doctor1 From:  <font color=red>2021-11-28 12:05:12</font> to  <font color=red>2021-11-30 12:00:00</font><br>
Doctor1 From: <font color=red>2021-11-01 00:00:00</font> to  <font color=red>2021-11-02 00:00:00</font><br>

<br><br>

<form method=POST>
<input name=docid value="Doctor1"><br>
<input name=startDateInput value=""> (e.g. 2021-11-28 1:0:0)<br>
<input name=endDateInput value=""> (e.g. 2021-11-30 12:0:0)<br>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

The above code can be seen LIVE at http://www.createchhk.com/SO/testSO28Nov2021a.php